# pushReplacementNamed doesn't replace it just pushes on top if coming from an AlertDialog

Tags: flutter

Here's the code:

3 FILES home, main, and screen1

MAIN:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home.dart';
import 'screen1.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
    routes:
    {
      '/home' : (context) => Home(),
      '/screen1': (context) => Screen1()
    },
  ));
}
```

HOME:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: (){Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/screen1');},
          child: Text('screen 1'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

screen1:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget homeDialog(BuildContext context){
  return AlertDialog(
    title: const Text('Do you want to exit'),
    actions: [
      ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('No'),
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Yes'),
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
}

class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
const Screen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<Screen1> createState() => _Screen1State();
}

class _Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading:  false,
       title: Text('screen 1'),
      leading: GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){showDialog(context: context, builder: homeDialog);},
      child: Icon(Icons.home)
      ),
    ),
   );
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The `Screen1` is missing. Would you please [edit] your question and add it?

Comment: my bad, just added it

Comment: Would you please improve the question a bit more? For example, if you go from `Home` to `Screen1` and then click `No` it should go to `Screen1`. Otherwise, it should go to `Home`. Is that it?

Comment: when from screen 1 alert dialog I tap yes it pushes home on top of screen 1 instead of replacing screen1, and if I go back to screen1  and repeat it would stack again and again...

Comment: try running this project yourself, and use flutter inspector and you'll see that it doesn't replace home with screen1 but rather stacks home on top of screen 1 even though I'm using pushReplacement

Comment: I see now what you meant. Let me write an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `showDialog(AlertDialog(...))` is itself going to be pushed as a new route. So, when doing [`Navigator.pushReplacementNamed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacementNamed.html) inside the alert it is going to replace the alert itself, not the previous screen. That's why `Home` and `Screen1` got stacked on each other.

To solve this problem an [`AlertDialog`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) should only return by a [`Navigator.pop(context, result)`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html) passing the result as an argument of it. The sources are going to be the following:

**AlertDialog**

```dart
Widget homeDialog(BuildContext context) {
  return AlertDialog(
    title: const Text('Do you want to exit'),
    actions: [
      ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('No'),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Yes'),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

**Screen1**

```
class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Screen1> createState() => _Screen1State();
}

class _Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text('screen 1'),
        leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {
              bool? yes =
                  await showDialog<bool>(context: context, builder: homeDialog);
              // `mounted` checks if this screen hasn't been disposed already.
              if (mounted) {
                if (yes == true) {
                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
                } else {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              }
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.home)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```